# Increasing Docker container size on Centos

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running a docker stack on Centos-7 box (not boot2docker) . I need to increase the size of the containers from 10GB (which is the default) to a higher value . How can I achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resizing Docker containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546490/resizing-docker-containers)

Answer (score 3):

More specifically you are asking to increase the `Docker daemon` default size for containers.

The value for this is determined by the `dm.basesize` option for the `--storage-opt` option. The default is not `10G` for the latest Docker version, it's `100G` as per [this](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/daemon/#storage-driver-options)

For `20G` you can run something like this:

```
docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G
```

Keep in mind if your OS fs is less than `20GB` it will default to the maximum of the fs.